# Play Framework WS.withQueryString - can't pass query string from request

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm new to Scala and the Play Framework.  I'm having troubles sending a web request using Play's play.api.libs.ws.WS.  I want to call an external API with the same query string and get the response.  Trouble I'm having is setting the withQueryString of WS

Example with request in context:

```
val queryString = request.queryString.map { case (k,v) => k -> v.mkString };
WS.url(someurl)
    .withQueryString(queryString.toList)
    .get()
```

I get error "type mismatch; found : List[(String, String)] required: (String, String)"

However, it appear that the withQueryString accepts many tuples, ie (String, String)*, just not a List of tuples.  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
.withQueryString(queryString.toList: _*)
```

Which is the standard Scala syntax for passing a collection of some type `A` to a method that accepts a variable number of arguments of `A` (in your case, `(String, String)`)